# Массив с помощью цикла PHP

Tags: php, json

Как можно создать массив типа

```html
<?php
[
  array(
    "name" => "Щи",
    "amount" => 1,
    "code" => "00031",
    "sum" => 80
  ),
  array(
    "name" => "Салат Коул-слоу",
    "amount" => 2,
    "code" => "0027",
    "sum" => 200
  )
 ]
```

Из декодированного `JSON`

```html
<?php 
array(5) {
  ["Пепперони"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "440"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totalPrice"]=>
    int(1320)
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "Пепперони"
    ["productSize"]=>
    string(7) "40 см"
  }
  ["4 сезона"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["price"]=>
    int(690)
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(188) "Томатный соус, орегано, кубики брынзы, шампиньоны, томаты, ветчина, пикантная пепперони и сыр моцарелла"
    ["totalPrice"]=>
    int(690)
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "4 сезона"
    ["image"]=>
    string(31) "assets/img/catalog/4seasons.JPG"
    ["productSize"]=>
    string(7) "40 см"
  }
  ["Земная"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "590"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totalPrice"]=>
    int(1180)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Земная"
    ["productSize"]=>
    string(7) "20 см"
  }
  ["Компания"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    int(2600)
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(151) "Земная 40 см, Цыпленок барбекю 40 см, 4 сезона 40 см, Шеф бекон 40 см, Сырный цыпленок 40 см"
    ["totalPrice"]=>
    int(2600)
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Компания"
    ["image"]=>
    string(32) "assets/img/kombo/company-min.jpg"
  }
  ["Бон аква не газ (0,5л)"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    int(80)
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totalPrice"]=>
    int(80)
    ["name"]=>
    string(35) "Бон аква не газ (0,5л)"
    ["image"]=>
    string(30) "assets/img/drinks/bonnegaz.jpg"
  }
}

//JSON
/*
  string(1114) "{"Пепперони":{"price":"440","quantity":"3","description":"","totalPrice":1320,"name":"Пепперони","productSize":"40 см"},"4 сезона":{"price":690,"quantity":"1","description":"Томатный соус, орегано, кубики брынзы, шампиньоны, томаты, ветчина, пикантная пепперони и сыр моцарелла","totalPrice":690,"name":"4 сезона","image":"assets/img/catalog/4seasons.JPG","productSize":"40 см"},"Земная":{"price":"590","quantity":"2","description":"","totalPrice":1180,"name":"Земная","productSize":"20 см"},"Компания":{"price":2600,"quantity":"1","description":"Земная 40 см, Цыпленок барбекю 40 см, 4 сезона 40 см, Шеф бекон 40 см, Сырный цыпленок 40 см","totalPrice":2600,"name":"Компания","image":"assets/img/kombo/company-min.jpg"},"Бон аква не газ (0,5л)":{"price":80,"quantity":"1","description":"","totalPrice":80,"name":"Бон аква не газ (0,5л)","image":"assets/img/drinks/bonnegaz.jpg"}}" 
*/
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Да никак - массивы совершенно разнородные. Где щи в JSONе ?

Comment: Сорри, за корявость, это случайные массивы вставил. Хочу понять сам принцип как разобрать JSON. Пробую сделать так  `foreach ($json as $key => $value){
  if (is_array($value)) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
      echo $key2 . " => " . $value2 . "<br>";
    }
  }
}` - но тут не могу понять как разъедить продукты в отдельные массивы, сейчас они все в куче

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$your_array = $ваш_массив_с_данными;
$new_array = [];
if ( ! empty($your_array) && is_array($your_array)) {
    foreach($your_array AS $key => $val) {
        $new_array[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое, то что нужно!

Comment: код в ответе аналогичен такому, `$new_array = array_values($your_array);`  или я что-то не понимаю Oo